# How to use gateway pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-mvc

I've an interceptor class where in postHandle method, I need to capture all the event request for my application for Audit. I want to implement the gateway pattern between my service and repository. I don't know how to implement the gateway layer which can convert my request object of `HttpServletRequest` to my domain object and pass it to repository layer. Below is my code:

```
  @Override
  public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, 
                         Object handler,
                         ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        auditService.save((Audit)reuest);
  }
```

How can I send the request object to service and then to repository through gateway?

Comment: 1. What data do you plan to save in audit?
2. Which gateway pattern do you have in mind? I believe it not this one: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm speaking from a Spring Integration stand-point, but this should apply).

The gateway pattern is used to put data into the system from a service. This "service" could be a simple java class or could be tied to a connector in same way to be input from an outside source. The gateway defines what "channel" is used and essentially what data is on that channel (though that need not be explicit).

To create a gateway, you would **define what data exists on the gateway** and **how that will connect** with other services. You could use [spring integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/gateway.html), or some form of Listeners. Or another. The choice is yours.

Define the gateway where the data comes into your system. This looks to be your Http Request Handler. Here you would push data into the gateway, and don't have a care what happens on the other end. You would then create two endpoints, one for your service so the data is processed correctly and one for your repository so an archive is maintained. (You could even add another later if you wanted.)